# Recommendations for an eCommerce back-end control panel

Tags: php, e-commerce

I have made many online stores before which have used my own back-end control panel to manage products and orders etc.

The reason for using my own back-end has been because:

1) The shops I have produced sites for sell a small range of specialist products which means it has not needed a complex back-end;

2) The designs have been bespoke and have not followed the conventional templates seen on zen-cart, os-commerce etc (not that there is anything wrong with these, it has just not been what the client has wanted).

I am aware that you can produce custom templates on most eCommerce software but it still requires you to use their app set up and over complicated structure (over complicated for my use).

In addition, I use backbonejs and underscore to manage my front end so I cannot easily intergreate with these custom templates.

**My question: Is there is a simple open-source eCommerce software out there, that only controls your back-end admin panel(products,orders,postage,payments, etc)but leaves the front end completely to you?**

Comment: Any reasons for the close votes? It has a legitimate question.

Comment: Yes, PHP would be best for me.

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework? I think Vendo for Kohana Framework is quite used. I'd recommend searching for a plugin/module for the framework you're using, or to choose a good MVC/HMVC php framework if you don't use one already :)